# ios uitextfield like notes

Tags: iphone, ios, background, uitextfield

I wish that my uitextfield seems like the notes of the iPhone, yellow with the lines..
what's the best way to do this?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean UItextview right? ... its not a UITextField.
However,   clear your background on the UITextView.

```
self.textView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor clearColor];
```

Then create ImageView that u put as a subview to your textview.

```
backgroundimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, -14,textView.frame.size.width, textView.fram.size.height)];
```

set a pattern image as backgroundColor.  This will be your lines. Just create on or two lines . Then it should repeat itself.

```
backgroundimage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lines.png"];
```

then add your subview to the textview.

```
[self.textView addSubview:backgroundimage];
```

Good luck!

Comment: instead af creating a backgroundView, just set the background color of your `UITextView` to `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lines.png"];`