# iOS 7 Notes Paper Background

Tags: ios, background, ios7, reminders

I wanted to use the same background on a UIView that is used on the Notes/Reminders iOS 7 apps.

Is this available on code or?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375350/uitextview-ruled-line-background-but-wrong-line-height and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098682/ios-uitextfield-like-notes and http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/03/stuff-you-learn-from-reverse-engineering-notes-app/

Answer (score 3):

Just take a a screen-shot, then use `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage]`